# CSS img align: how to set a img middle-right align in a DIV

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am looking for a simple way to middle-right align a img in a DIV, i.e., vertical-middle and horizontal-right align, like this:

[image]

I tried using vertical-align:middle and float:right in IMG styles, but seems not work together..

```
<div style='height: 300px; width: 300px'>
    <img src= 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif' style='vertical-align: middle; float: right;'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DIV style='height: 300px; width: 300px;border:1px solid #ff0000;display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle'>
<img src= 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif' style='float:right;'/>
</DIV>
```

BTW, you are using "styles=" in your image tag. This is invalid.

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do this. It is very easy if image and its container height is known, tricky otherwise. Choose the solution that suit your needs:

**Method 1: line height, text-align and vertical align**

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: right;
}
#div1 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png">&#8203;
</div>
```

**Method 2: absolute/relative positioning, image height known**

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
#div1 img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px; /* -(image_height/2) */
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png">
</div>
```

**Method 3: absolute/relative positioning, image and container height known**

```css
#div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#div1 img {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 125px; /* (div_height-image_height)/2 */
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png">
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/CsbDp/)**

Answer (score 0):

The `display: table-cell` trick works well if it is just an image floating in a div. But if you have other elements crowding the image, such as `<p>`, they will tend to push the image around vertically as they are resized by the browser.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html has some good information on cross browser support and earlier browser version hacks to get the image displaying correctly in IE's broken box model.